# Как сделать snapshoot test react component portal?

Tags: reactjs, юнит-тесты

```
16 |   const isActiveModal = useSelector(getIsActiveModal);
      17 |   const domElement = React.useRef(document.getElementById('portal'));
    > 18 |   return ReactDOM.createPortal(
         |                   ^
      19 |     <div
      20 |       className={isActiveModal ? 'backdrop active' : 'backdrop'}
      21 |       onClick={() => dispatch(setModal({ isActiveModal: false, formModal: formModal.login }))}
```

такая ошибка.

сам тест

```
import Header from '../Header';
import { renderComponentWithStore } from '../../../utils/TestHelpers';
// import * as ReactDOMPortal from 'react-dom';

// jest.spyOn(ReactDOMPortal, 'createPortal');

it('renders correctly Country-card', () => {
  const { container } = renderComponentWithStore({
    Component: Header,
    preloadedState: {
      infoCountries: {
        listCountries: [],
        fullInfoCountry: [],
        isFullInfoCountry: false,
        isLoading: false,
        infoErrorResponse: '',
      },
      infoUser: {
        userName: '',
        listFavoriteCountries: [],
        isAuthentication: false,
        infoModal: { isActiveModal: false, formModal: 'login' },
      },
    },
  });
  expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Часть компонета модальки, на него ещё тест не писал, ошибку покзывает в этом файле.

```
return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div
      className={isActiveModal ? 'backdrop active' : 'backdrop'}
      onClick={() => dispatch(setModal({ isActiveModal: false, formModal: formModal.login }))}
    >
      <div
        className={isActiveModal ? 'modal-container active' : 'modal-container'}
        onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>,
    // document.getElementById('portal') as HTMLElement,
    domElement.current as HTMLElement,
    // document.root.nextElementSibling,
//document.body
  );
```

Тест проходит если писать document.body, но надо чтобы модалка была ребёноком в div portal, а не сосоедом его